# Lambda Expression on boolean

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, boolean

What is the correct syntax for lambda expression for a bool value comparrison?

The example below shows `rsp.InputOutput` which is a bool value. However I get a compiler error when I try to do this. I know its something small, any help appreciated.

In this examplem I want to select all rulesetparameters which have an `InputOutput` value of `true`.

```
validRuleSetParameters.SelectMany(rsp => rsp.InputOutput == true)
```

thanks
Niall

Comment: thanks guys. thats absolutely what i wanted. cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the `Where` clause:

```
var ruleSetPars = validRuleSetParameters.Where(rsp => rsp.InputOutput);
```

`SelectMany` is quite different; it is used when you want to project each member of a sequence to another *sequence*, and then flatten the resulting sequence-of-sequences into a single sequence.

Do note that if `InputOutput` is a boolean property, `rsp.InputOutput` is *already* a boolean-expression. Consequently, using the equality operator to produce *another* boolean expression (by comparing its value with the literal bool `true`) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
validRuleSetParameters.Where(rsp => rsp.InputOutput)
```

Edit:
Where will find all the entries for which the lambda is true. SelectMany is used for flattening a sequence of IEnumerables.
Edit 2: Removed == true

Comment: The comparison with `true` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

```
validRuleSetParameters.Where(rsp => rsp.InputOutput);
```